# Closing different ends in a pipe

Tags: linux, pipe, c

I have wrote the following code for IPC using `pipe()` :

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
    
    
int main(void) {
    char message_buffer[15] = "Hello World \n";  
    char read_buffer[15];
    int fd[2]; 
   
    int return_value = pipe(fd);
   
    if (return_value < 0) {
        printf("Error creating the pipe");
    }
    
    int rc = fork();
    if (rc  < 0) {
        printf("Error forking a child");
    }
    
    if (rc > 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], message_buffer, 15);
        close(fd[1]);
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], read_buffer, 15);
        close(fd[0]);
        printf("The Message: %s", read_buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am new to pipes, and I have the following questions:

1. I don't understand why the parent needs to close the read side before writing and needs to close the write side after writing?
2. Same for child, why does it need to close the write side before reading, and then why it need to close the read side after reading?
3. Since the parent and the child run concurrently, what will happen if the child reads while the parent is writing the message?
4. Since the parent and the child run concurrently, what will happen if the child reads and the parent didn't yet write anything in the pipe?

My questions seems to be stupid but please help to answer them as I am learning ordinary pipes for my course exam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to **questions 1 and 2** is in the `pipe` [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html#EXAMPLES) (section "Examples"):

> After the fork, each process closes the file descriptors that it doesn't need for the pipe (see pipe(7)).

As the pipe is unidirectional, it has designated ends - the *read* end and the *write* end. If this pipe is going to be used by the parent to write data to the child, there is no point for the parent to keep the read end open. Reversely, if the child is going to read the data from the pipe, it does not need to have the write end open.

But a **more important reason** for closing unneeded ends of the pipe was [described](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693792/56572) by user @ilkkachu. Please, check out the linked answer.

**Edit:**

You also asked why does the parent need to close the write side after writing  and why does the child need to close the read end after reading.

They do not have to. If two programs are going to continue running and exchanging the data using the pipe, they will have to keep it open. In a short example program that merely demonstrates the use of the pipe and which terminates after transmission of one message, the parent and the child close the pipe file descriptors perhaps for the sake of properly cleaning up the resources before the program terminates.

The answers to the question #3 and #4 are in the `pipe(7)` [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

**Your question #3:**

> Since the parent and the child can run concurrently , what will happen
> if the child read while the parent is writing the message ??

The child will be able to read whatever data is available in the pipe that was already written by the parent. According to the man page:

> POSIX.1 says that writes of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be atomic:
> the output data is written to the pipe as a contiguous sequence.
> Writes of more than PIPE_BUF bytes may be nonatomic: the kernel may
> interleave the data with data written by other processes.  POSIX.1
> requires PIPE_BUF to be at least 512 bytes. (On Linux, PIPE_BUF is
> 4096 bytes.)

**Your question #4:**

> Since the parent and the child can run concurrently , what will happen
> if the child read and the parent didn't yet write anything in the pipe
> ??

The man page says:

> If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe, then read(2)
> will block until data is available.  If a process attempts to
> write to a full pipe (see below), then write(2) blocks until
> sufficient data has been read from the pipe to allow the write to
> complete.

**Answers to questions from the comments:**

> For question 1 and 2 , this means that if I didn't close the unneeded
> ends this will not affect the program by any means ?

It should not prevent the pipe from working, but it will create some footprint on the resources used by the program. By closing the unneeded ends of the pipe, these resources are not being held.

> For question 3 , this means that the child will read what is being
> written by the parent , how the the child will know that the parent
> has finished what it need to write ?

The man page says:

> The communication channel provided by a pipe is a byte stream:
> there is no concept of message boundaries.

It means that the pipe does not care about the data you transmit. It does not know what a "message" means or whether the parent has finished writing or it wants to write more data.

You will need to implement your own technique for determining what a "full message" is. For example, the parent can signify to the child that a full message has been written by sending a special character, for example `\0` or actually anything else which will make sense in a particular context where the pipe is being used.

Comment: Thanks alot . For question 1 and 2 , this means that if I didnt close the unneeded ends this will not affect the program by any means ? For question 3 , this means that the child will read what is being written by the parent , how the the child will know that the parent has finished what it need to write ?

Comment: @AAA See my edits.

Answer (score 4):

See the [`pipe(7)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

Under "I/O on pipes and FIFOs", it says:

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have
> been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see
> end-of-file (read(2) will return 0).

> If all file descriptors
> referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a
> write(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the
> calling process.

Having the child close its copy of the write end (which it's not going to use), makes it possible for the child to detect when the *parent* does so. If the child kept the write end open, it'd never see an EOF on the pipe, since it would essentially be waiting for itself. (2)

Similarly, having the parent close its copy of the read end also lets the parent detect if the child goes away. (1)

Not that the code you have there ever checks the return values of `read()` and `write()` or tries to read/write a variable amount of data, so that's basically moot apart from the parent getting the SIGPIPE signal.

Closing the write end in the parent after writing and closing the read end after reading in the child is just common housekeeping. If the processes exit right after anyway, explicitly closing won't make a difference.

I'm not sure if your questions 3 and 4 are the same, but if the reader reads when there's nothing to read, the system call will block:

> If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe, then read(2)
> will block until data is available.

If the writer writes when the reader is doing something else, the data will be copied to a buffer in the OS, at least if there's enough space. If there isn't, then the writer will block:

> If a process attempts to
> write to a full pipe (see below), then write(2) blocks until
> sufficient data has been read from the pipe to allow the write to
> complete.

That "below" is the section on "Pipe capacity".

If they do it at the same time, the OS will just copy the data on.

Comment: Thank you  . Regarding closing the unused ends , If I didn't do so my program works fine , although you have said that if the child don't close the write end , it will block and wait for itself , so why this didn't happen to me and the program didn't hangup ?

Comment: @AAA, well, in general it might block. But in your case, there's one `write()` from one process, and one `read()` from the other, and the amount of data is small. So the read and write match up and after that's done, both process go on doing something else. You could try with having the reader read in a loop, something like `while (1) { n = read(...); if (n == -1) { handle error...; break } else if (n == 0) { handle eof; break } else { do something with the n bytes read } }`

Answer (score 4):

Others have provided nice answers.  This is an extension of ilkkachu's comment on his answer above, and is intended to help you experimentally.  Consider the following program, which is a slightly modified version of what you posted originally:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct message {
    char content[15];
};

int main(void) {
    int fds[2];

    if (pipe(fds) < 0) {
        printf("Error creating the pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    const pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("Error forking a child");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid > 0) {
        const int message_count = (rand() % 9) + 1;
        const struct message message_buffer = {
            .content = "Hello, World\n",
        };

        /* 1 */ close(fds[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < message_count; ++i) {
            write(fds[1], &message_buffer, sizeof(message_buffer));
        }

        /* 2 */ close(fds[1]);

        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        struct message read_buffer;

        /* 3 */ close(fds[1]);

        while (read(fds[0], &read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer)) > 0) {
            printf("The Message: %s", read_buffer.content);
        }

        /* 4 */ close(fds[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This version doesn't send *a* message, it sends a random number of messages between 1 and 10.  This way, the child doesn't know ahead of time how many message to read -- it stops when it has read everything from the pipe *and nothing else can be written to the pipe* (i.e., when all the write-ends are closed and `read` returns a negative value).  Here's a couple of sample runs:

```
$ ./a.out
The Message: Hello, World
$ ./a.out
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
$ ./a.out
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
$
```

Notice that I've put comments before each of the calls to `close()` associated with the pipe.  If you comment out only line (1), there's no noticeable change to the program's behavior:

```
$ ./a.out
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
$ ./a.out
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
$
```

If you comment out only line (2), then the program deadlocks when you run it, for example:

```
$ ./a.out
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
(program hangs here)
```

Why? If the parent process does not close the write-end of the pipe, then the child will block forever in the call to `read` waiting more more data. (The `read` call will block if there's *any* open file descriptor associated with the write-end of the pipe.)  The parent will then block forever in the call to `wait`.  Both the parent and the child block forever waiting for each other.

If you comment out only line (3), then the program deadlocks when you run it, for example:

```
$ ./a.out
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
(program hangs here)
```

Why?  Again, the call to `read` will block as long as there exists *any* open file descriptor associated with the write-end of the pipe, and the child has one.  As a result, again the child blocks in the call to `read` and the the parent blocks in the call to `wait` and nothing makes any further progress.

Finally, if you comment out only line (4), then there's no noticeable change to the program's behavior:

```
$ ./a.out
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
$ ./a.out
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
The Message: Hello, World
$
```

By ensuring that all processes close the file descriptors that they don't need, you ensure that no process ends up blocked waiting to read data from the pipe that will never come.

Answer (score 0):

Not properly closing the unused pipe descriptors makes an important difference under certain circumstances:

1. Why the writer should close the read-descriptor

An attempt to write to a pipe with no reader generates the `SIGPIPE` signal. This should happen when the reader is gone (e.g. process has exited).

But when the writer keeps the pipe's read-descriptor open, no `SIGPIPE` can occur, because technically the pipe is not broken, the writer itself is a possible reader.

2. Why the reader should close the write-descriptor

Closing a pipe generates the EOF condition. If the reader does not close its copy of the write-descriptor, the writer is unable to send EOF, because more data can be still written to the pipe by the reader.